# pandas pivot table with average time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have been working with pandas to do analysis on time series data and have become stuck with integrating them into pivot tables. I have a data in a csv as:

```
gov start   end
a   2015-12-08T16:05:00.980+03  2015-12-08T16:14:31.765+03
a   2015-12-08T16:07:53.356+03  2015-12-08T16:34:43.413+03
b   2015-12-08T16:08:43.371+03  2015-12-08T16:54:32.257+03
b   2015-12-08T15:56:12.006+03  2015-12-08T17:35:04.499+03
```

I have a simple set of data with a `start` and `end` time, and from that work out the time difference between the two:

```
piv_t_subset = pd.read_csv('time_test.csv', parse_dates=['start','end'])

piv_t_subset['time_diff'] = piv_t_subset['end'] - piv_t_subset['start']
```

I can calculate the standalone mean value of time as:

```
t = piv_t_subset['time_diff'].mean()
print t

0 days 00:18:53.703286
```

I want to create a pivot table with this time information but when I try:

```
pd.pivot_table(piv_t_subset,index=["gov"],values=['time_diff'],aggfunc=[np.mean])
```

I get the error:

> DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Do I need to do more preprocessing to convert this from `timeseries` to `float`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it is not supported [link](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5724).

But you can convert `Series` of `timedelta64` to `Series` of `float` by [`total_seconds`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds):

```
piv_t_subset['time_diff1'] = [td.total_seconds() for td in piv_t_subset['time_diff']]
```

```
print piv_t_subset
  gov                   start                     end
0   a 2015-12-08 13:05:00.980 2015-12-08 13:14:31.765
1   a 2015-12-08 13:07:53.356 2015-12-08 13:34:43.413
2   b 2015-12-08 13:08:43.371 2015-12-08 13:54:32.257
3   b 2015-12-08 12:56:12.006 2015-12-08 14:35:04.499

piv_t_subset['time_diff'] = piv_t_subset['end'] - piv_t_subset['start']

piv_t_subset['time_diff1'] = [td.total_seconds() for td in piv_t_subset['time_diff']]
print piv_t_subset
  gov                   start                     end       time_diff  \
0   a 2015-12-08 13:05:00.980 2015-12-08 13:14:31.765 00:09:30.785000   
1   a 2015-12-08 13:07:53.356 2015-12-08 13:34:43.413 00:26:50.057000   
2   b 2015-12-08 13:08:43.371 2015-12-08 13:54:32.257 00:45:48.886000   
3   b 2015-12-08 12:56:12.006 2015-12-08 14:35:04.499 01:38:52.493000   

   time_diff1  
0     570.785  
1    1610.057  
2    2748.886  
3    5932.493  

print piv_t_subset.groupby('gov').agg({'time_diff1':np.mean})
     time_diff1
gov            
a     1090.4210
b     4340.6895

#omit aggfunc, in pivot_table is default numpy.mean
print pd.pivot_table(piv_t_subset,index=["gov"],values=['time_diff1'])
     time_diff1
gov            
a     1090.4210
b     4340.6895
```